# Why does laravel serialize session data instead of session encode/decode

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

Normally sessions are decoded with `session_encode` and `session_decode` whenever you start/close a session.

I know session encode/decode works a little bit different than serialize and produces different results from what I have seen.

I am wondering why Laravel chooses to go with `serialize` and `unserialize` for session data instead of doing:

```
session_encode()
session_decode($data)
```

What is the benefit of not using the native session encode/decoder?

An example of this being done can be found here:

https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/master/Store.php#L128

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `session_encode()` serializes the `$_SESSION` global. so `serialize($_SESSION)` is almost the same.

From the docs: 
By default, the serialization method used is internal to PHP, and is not the same as serialize().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php

With the `serialize($value)` you can determine yourself what you want to serialize and because laravel uses it's own session implementation they are forced to use the `serialize` method. Note that they could use the `json_encode` method which is faster but has some other disadvantages, `serialize` takes the data type in consideration and data can be deserialized to objects while `json_*` can't

Laravel doesn't use the `session_start` method and the `$_SESSION` global isn't available.

Basically the PHP implementation for sessions are left out by laravel because of a few shortcomings in the PHP implementation. The custom/laravel implementation is more flexible.

Note from the laravel source

```
    // If a session driver has been configured, we will need to start the session here
    // so that the data is ready for an application. Note that the Laravel sessions
    // do not make use of PHP "native" sessions in any way since they are crappy.
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L53

**Why are php native sessions crappy?**

I think (opinion) the main problem with the native PHP sessions is that you can't throw exceptions etc. This makes it harder to debug, or to maintain nice stack traces. By implementing an own session manager you have more control about when and where the session are stored/closed to maintain your own application flow.

> Warning As of PHP 5.0.5 the write and close handlers are called after object
>   destruction and therefore cannot use objects or throw exceptions.
>   Exceptions are not able to be caught since will not be caught nor will
>   any exception trace be displayed and the execution will just cease
>   unexpectedly. The object destructors can however use sessions.

Also this point could be a problem

> Warning When using objects as session save handlers, it is important
>   to register the shutdown function with PHP to avoid unexpected
>   side-effects from the way PHP internally destroys objects on shutdown
>   and may prevent the write and close from being called. Typically you
>   should register 'session_write_close' using the
>   register_shutdown_function() function.

Comment: Do note the `since they are crappy` phrase!

Comment: What exactly are these shortcomings? Do you have any reading material on this? Would love to know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Stephan-v Session deserialization code injection + execution https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/PHP_Object_Injection it all depends on what you store please note this is a problem directly associated with serialize and unserialize and not directly with sessions themselves, although they use this mechanism by default